# How to combine character (or numeric) variables with expressions at LEGEND in R

Tags: r, character, expression, legend

When using R to plot three lines with legend that combines expression and character variables, I wrote, for example:

```
b1<-2
c1<-3
d1<-4
a<-seq(1,10)
b<-a+b1
c<-a+c1
d<-a+d1

plot(NA
 ,axes = FALSE       
 ,xlim=c(0,10)
 ,ylim=c(0,15)
 )
box()

lines(a,b,col=1)
lines(a,c,col=2)
lines(a,d,col=3)

legend(8,2
,c(expression(paste(italic(b)[1],"=2","m"))
,expression(paste(italic(c)[1],"=3","m"))
,expression(paste(italic(d)[1],"=4","m"))
  )
      )
```

The above scripts yields exactly the legend I want, However, the value b1, c1 and d1 are hard coded in the script.

Is there any way to put variable b1, c1 and d1 in the legend script? I have tried many ways, such as

no1.

```
b2<-as.character(b1)
legend(6,2
,c(expression(paste(italic(b)[1],b2,"m"))
,expression(paste(italic(c)[1],"=3","m"))
,expression(paste(italic(d)[1],"=4","m"))
  )
      )
```

no2.

```
legend(4,2
 ,c(bquote(paste(italic(b) [1], "=",.(b1),"m" ))

,expression(paste(italic(c)[1],"=3","m"))
,expression(paste(italic(d)[1],"=4","m"))
  )
      )
```

this one works for the first line, but if I make three lines by bquote, it doesn't work anymore:

```
legend(2,2
 ,c(bquote(paste(italic(b) [1], "=",.(b1),"m" ))

,bquote(paste(italic(b) [1], "=",.(b1),"m" ))
,bquote(paste(italic(b) [1], "=",.(b1),"m" ))
  )
      )
```

Any great ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
lgnd <- c(bquote(italic(b)[1] == .(b1)*m),
          bquote(italic(c)[1] == .(c1)*m),
          bquote(italic(d)[1] == .(d1)*m))
legend(2,4, as.expression(lgnd))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that should give you what you want doesn't it ?

```
leg<-as.factor(paste("m =",c(b1,c1,d1)))
legend("bottomright", levels(leg), lwd=1, lty=1, col=c(1,2,3), cex=1.25)
```

I may have misassiociated the lines and the legend levels, up to you to correct it ! ;)